# Upgrade to OS X Lion broke TortoiseSVN. Now getting database errors (SQLite?)

Tags: macos, svn, tortoise-svn

It was suggested over on Stack Overflow that I post my issue over here. Hope someone has some answers. =)

I've been running SVN 1.6 on my development Mac Mini since getting it earlier this year (to start iOS dev). But my main machine at work is a Windows 7 (64 bit) computer. It's where I have Photoshop and all my other development software. I was having some issues with checking in some files that upgrading TortoiseSVN to 1.7 solved.

Last week I finally upgraded the Mac Mini to Lion and now TortoiseSVN suddenly cannot communicate with the repository on the Mac Mini. It simply gives the error:

```
Error: database is locked, executing statement 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;PRAGMA  
Error:  recursive_triggers=ON;'
```

It was doing this for commits... I've tried to do a new checkout, clean up, update, etc. And they all give this error. I even tried to check out a new copy from Terminal on the Mini and then create a new SVN 1.7 working copy from TortoiseSVN and got the same error.

I'm planning on downgrading TortoiseSVN after posting this and I guess if the issues I used to have comes back at least I'll be getting work done...

Did anyone else stumble across this after upgrading to Lion? The current versions are as follows:

```
SVN: 1.6.17 (installed from CollabNet)
TortoiseSVN: 1.7.2 64 bit
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check the permissions of the SVN database files.

Comment: Also, please clarify, does checking out from Terminal of the server work, or does it have the same problem?

Comment: The permissions on the repository haven't changed. They work fine with TortoiseSVN 1.6.16. Of course that also means that with downgrading the working copy is now 1.6 instead of 1.7. 

And yes, I didn't have any issues checking out new copies directly on the server.

Comment: Did you upgrade the subversion server on the mac mini, or rebuild it for Lion?